# How do I loop the action on mousedown in easeljs

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I am creating a basic text window in easeljs. The text window has up and down scroll arrows to enable the scrolling of the text. I do this simply by listening for a click on the up or down button and then moving the y coordinates of the text box on the click.

The problem I have is that it only moves once per click. If I have a lot of text to scroll, I have to click a lot of times. What I want is to be able to click and hold the button and have the listener repeat the action whilst the mouse is down?

Here's my simplified code attached to the down button:

```
btn_down.on("mousedown", function(evt) {
    content.y -= 20;                
    game.stage.update();
});
```

I have tried mousedown and click, but it still only seems to fire once.

Answer (score 0):

The mousedown event fires once (when you press your mouse button). If you want to loop an event while the mouse is down, either set an interval when the mouse is pressed (and clear it when it is released), or toggle a property that causes an update during a tick.

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/t7uz2v6m/

```
shape.on("mousedown", handlePress);
shape.on("pressup", handleRelease); 

var pressed = false;
function handlePress(event) { pressed = true; }
function handleRelease(event) { pressed = false; }

function tick(event) {
    if (pressed) { shape2.x += 1; }
    stage.update(event);
}
```

Note that I use the "pressup" event instead of the mouseup equivalent (click), because if you roll out and release, the "pressup" event still fires.

Cheers.